# MongoDB: findOne returns null but document exists in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to send an email and password server-side and check if a document with those values exists (which it does), but when I console log the `results` from the query it's null.

Here's the document in the `users` collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("580bcf9874ae28934705c0fc"),
    "email" : "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "password" : "pass"
}
```

Here's what I'm sending server-side:

```
{"email":"johndoe@gmail.com","password":"pass"}
```

Here's my code (updated):

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function (err, db) {

    if (err) {
    console.log("error: " + err); // logs nothing
    } else {

        var users = db.collection("users");
        var tasks = db.collection("tasks");

        app.post("/login", function(req, res) {

            var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            var userInDb;
            var userEmail = req.body.email;
            var userPassword = req.body.password;

            console.log(req.body.email); // logs "johndoe@gmail.com"
            console.log(req.body.password); // logs "pass"

            if (!userEmail || !userPassword) {
                return res.sendStatus(403);
            } else if ( !emailRegex.test(userEmail)) {
                return res.sendStatus(403);
            } else {

                users.findOne( { "email": userEmail, "password": userPassword }, function(err, results) {

                    console.log(results); // logs "null"

                    if(err) {
                      console.log("error: " + err); // logs nothing
                      res.sendStatus(403);
                    } else {
                      console.log("here"); // logs "here"
                      res.sendStatus(200);
                    }

                  });
              }
          });
       }
    });
```

Comment: Try `console.log` the error. Do you get anything?

Comment: @nicovank It returns 'null'.

Comment: And `console.log(req.body.email)` and `console.log(req.body.password)`?

Comment: @nicovank They're returning what's expected, respectively: `johndoe@gmail.com` and `pass`

Comment: ~same problem, maybe data corruption?~

Answer (score 2):

each time you pass a callback that has an error parameter, it's your responsibility to check if an error was passed, and if so, deal with it.

in your code, you have two such callbacks:

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function (err, db)
users.findOne( { "email": userEmail, "password": userPassword }, function(err, results)
```

either one of them can return an error object that might explain the issue.
add the following to the first line of each callback:

```
if (err) {
  return console.log("error: " + err);
}
```

Comment: I updated the description. Neither error is being logged.

Comment: either there's a typo in the email/pass or there's no doc in the collection, when you change the findOne line to: users.findOne( { }, function(... does it then show *any* document?

Comment: No, none. But when I query in Terminal it returns the document. Does it have to do with the location of the database in my filesystem v. where my script is trying to query from? Or maybe an issue with auth over that location?

Comment: Kinda figured this out. Although I had a document with that data, it appears to have been in a different place than where my script was looking. Not sure how that happened since I thought all data was in `/data/db/`, but looking into it.

Comment: Lol ... a year later I am suffering exactly the same mysterious error ...

Comment: In my case, I was taking result at the first position in the callback function. HaHaHa!!!

Comment: Did anyone solve this error? @SpencerK.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me.
I had to call `toArray()` method.
I don't remember how I found that solution, cuz in MongoDB manuals they don't call to array method

```
users.findOne( { "email": userEmail, "password": userPassword }).toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a simular problem in one of my project. It is all because I stored the collection and the document in a database which is different from which my app is connected to. Check that once.

Comment: this should be a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

It is really mysterious, I think MongoDB client should make a fix on it.
MongoDB is not very reliable. Often get lose connection in 1/10 of requests. But the very annoying is, it returns an empty array instead of an error in connection, that makes us impossible to catch connection error.

Because I use the existence of documents in DB to reinitialize the project, I really get annoyed of it.  CouchDB will not have this problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

```
users.findOne({'email' :  userEmail , 'password':userPassword }, function(err, result) {

console.log("result:"+result);
});
```

Comment: It's pretty obvious that he has logged everything and has found that his query is not returning anything despite the presence of the record in the collection. I have the same issue, and I have logged everything.